# Grab immediate directory on URL

Tags: javascript

How can I use JavaScript to scrape the URL and then use the first directory of the URL. So for example if I had a URL like `domain.com/Organisations/Manage` the bit I would want to use is `Organisations`.

Note that this app can also run in development modes where it has prefixes on the url such as `localhost:8888/AppName/Organisations/Manage`

The reason for this is to apply the name to the body as an Id such as `<body id="Organisations">`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to slice up `document.location.pathname`.  If `"Organisations"` always second from the last part of the path, then you could use this:

```
document.location.pathname.split("/").slice(-2, -1).toString();
//-> "Organisations"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick as well:

```
document.location.origin + "/" + document.location.pathname.split("/")[1]
```